Recomposition when state changed partially
I'm playing with Compose and trying to come up with the idea of how to update state with as less overhead as possible.
Imagine situation like this
@Composable
internal fun PokemonScreen(
    model: Contract.Model,
) {
    Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            modifier = Modifier.width(32.dp)
        )
        PokemonsList(pokemons = model.pokemons)
        Button(onClick = {}) {
            Text("${model.loading}")
        }
    }
}

As far as I understand if I do
setContent {
    PokemonScreen(model = state.value)
}

where state is MutableState<Contract.Model>
every time I do state.value = newState the whole PokemonScreen would be recomposed.
But what if the state has changed just partially, for example just loading member has switched from true to false? Well it seems it doesn't matter and the whole screen would be recomposed anyways. Hence the question - how do I manage the state in a way that if just loading changes then just Button's lambda gets recomposed? So far I can think of creating separate State vals for each of State's member and passing them into PokemonScreen like this
@Composable
internal fun PokemonScreen(
    loading: State<Boolean>,
) 

but it seems a bit cumbersome.
Any best practices here? Am I doing something wrong?

Does this answer your question? How to prevent unnecessary recompositions in Jetpack Compose
